# How to implement django admin queryset filter with from extended user model class

Tags: python-3.x, django-admin, django-queryset

I have extended Django default User model (just to save user state_id) class with following model.

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    state_id = models.IntegerField(blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.user.username
```

And now I want to filter the data by logged user's `state_id`. I tried to implement queryset filter but it does not do anything.

```
class VisVisitsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_per_page = 10
    list_display = ('visit_id','visit_no','user_name','mobile_number','program_name','state_name','district_name','block_name','school_name',)

    list_filter = ('date_of_visit',)

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(VisVisitsAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(state_id=request.user.UserProfileInfo.state_id)

    def state_name(self, obj):
        if obj.school_program:
            return obj.school_program.school.cluster.block.district.state.name_of_state
    state_name.short_description = 'state name'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to fetch the state_id from the userprofileinfo instance related to user object.

Everything seems fine but the instance is available as `userprofileinfo` and not `UserProfileInfo` , so change qs as :

```
qs.filter(state_id=request.user.userprofileinfo.state_id)
```